# Upload blob parallelly in chunks using storage-file-datalake JS

Tags: azure-storage

How to use Upload blob parallelly in chunks using storage-file-datalake  JS

const dataLakeFileSystemClient= new DataLakeFileSystemClient(
url,
new AnonymousCredential(),
customPipeline
);

dataLakeFileSystemClient
.upload(blob, {
abortSignal: aborter,
chunkSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024,
concurrency: 20,
maxSingleShotSize: 100 * 1024 * 1024,
maxConcurrency: 20,
onProgress: (ev) => {
let percentComplete = ev.loadedBytes / blob.size;
let loadedBytes = ev.loadedBytes;
emitter({ percentComplete, loadedBytes });
},
}

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me.**

const customPipeline = newPipeline(new AnonymousCredential());

```
const dataLakeServiceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(
  url,
  new AnonymousCredential(),
  customPipeline
);

const fileSystemClient =
  dataLakeServiceClient.getFileSystemClient(containerName);

const fileClient = fileSystemClient.getFileClient(blobName);

const aborter = Azure.Aborter.none;

fileClient
  .upload(blob, {
    abortSignal: aborter,
    chunkSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024,
    concurrency: 20,
    maxSingleShotSize: 100 * 1024 * 1024,
    maxConcurrency: 20,
    onProgress: (ev) => {
      let percentComplete = ev.loadedBytes / blob.size;
      let loadedBytes = ev.loadedBytes;
      emitter({ percentComplete, loadedBytes });
    },
  })
```